# Ubuntu Login Loop with Ctrl+Alt+F3 Terminal unable to execute commands

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, login

Like the question says, I'm caught in a standard Ubuntu Login Loop. However I have been unable to resolve this with the information from pre-existing posts.

(Fyi I'm using zsh and am unable to change back to bash on the Ctrl alt F3 Terminal with either `bash` or `source .bashrc`)

I am unable to execute any commands on this terminal screen and so cannot update drivers or check any files.

For example if I try `ls` am I returned:

```
zsh: command not found: ls
spaceship_jobs:3: command not found: ask
spaceship_jobs:3: command not found: WC
spaceship_jobs:3: command not found: tr
```

To reiterate my goal is to fix the Ubuntu Login Loop so if a fix to that exists without fixing the Ctrl alt F3 Terminal that's fine.

If you need any more specific information please contact me.

Comment: What happens if you use an absolute path to the commands (`/bin/ls`, `/bin/bash`)?

Comment: It changes to that directory but the error messages still come up